# Groovy script. Is pointless to assert an element is present, after a wait until same element is present?

Tags: groovy, ready-api

I'm using ReadyApi and Groovy script here.

Basically I have inherited a set of tests created on ReadyAPI on groovy script and I'm learning from what's there. Its automated tests for navigating around a webpage

The same few lines are used every time a new page is navigated to.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h1[contains(., 'X')]")));
def example = theDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[contains(., 'X')]")).getText();
assert example.contains("X");
log.info( "Page " + example + " is present");
```

Is it a completely pointless exercise to assert h1 contains X, when you already have a wait until the h1 is present?

I know its just one line but its bugging me

Comment: well you still need some sort of assert to mark the test passed. Thats why you always put ids in your elements. Then as a general standard, wait until the element is present and assert on some value inside that element. Here since the xpaths are exactly same they are redundant

Comment: Seems question about selenium and not about readyapi. If true then it really depends on what is in `wait` variable. If it's `explicit wait` then it will throw timeoutexception on condition failure - so, all following assertions on the same condition are meaningless. If it's a `fluent wait` then it will not throw exception and you need an assertion to throw exception.  https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @Kaus2b I think I understand what you are saying. Maybe it would be better to wait for one xpath, then do an assertion on a different xpath on the same page?

Comment: @RogerDodger Yeah. So lets say there is a field `<label id="myField">some text</label>` Then you wait for element with id myField and assert on some text for test to pass